# SQL query - count with subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count, subquery

I want to get the count of all the columns that are retrieved in the query.I have used the below code:

```
select count (*) 
from ( 
   select distinct ID,salary,name,location 
   from test 
) ;
```

I am getting an error message:

> Incorrect error at ; expecting AS,ID or quoted_ID

When I add as below:

```
select count (*) 
from (
   select distinct ID,salary,name,location 
   from test 
) as count;
```

The query works now but the column name is not renamed to the alias given. What is the logic behind this?

Comment: Some DBMS require derived tables to have an alias, some don't. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 08,My concern is even after giving the alias name the column name is not changed,it is displayed as No column name.

Comment: You gave the derived table an alias, not the column. If you want to give the **column** an alias you have to specify it _there_, `count(*) as count from (...) as x`

Comment: this makes sense now.Thanks a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1):

In Sql you have to give alias to subquery. So that's the reason the second query works and first one fails

Comment: The second query works but the column name is not renamed with the alias name given in query,it is displayed as "no column name"

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what you are trying to achieve but to correct this would be

```
select count (*) from (select distinct ID,salary,name,location from test ) as myTAble;
```

> subquery will act as your table to query from therefore it needs a
>   name or alias

Comment: Alias name should be used just after the column which is supposed to be renamed that is before "from" .Anyhow in this code,the column name is displayed without the alias name

Comment: will to put it officially a derived table needs to have a name as far as i know

Answer (score 1):

You are giving alias to the table and not column. The following query would work.

```
select count (*) As count
    from (
       select distinct ID,salary,name,location 
       from test 
    ) as tbl;
```